# How to narrow down perf.data to a time sub interval

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, perf

I use linux perf (perf_events) to produce a perf.data file with timestamps.

How can I generate a report of all the events in a sub interval of time [i-start, i-end]?

Can I maybe narrow down perf.data to a perf_subinterv.data file with only events in [i-start, i-end]?

I need to do this to analyze short intervals (2s - 6s) of poor performance every 5mins or so.

Answer (score 8):

Most `perf` tools, including `perf report`, support filtering by time:

> ```
> --time::
>   Only analyze samples within given time window: <start>,<stop>. Times
>   have the format seconds.microseconds. If start is not given (i.e., time
>   string is ',x.y') then analysis starts at the beginning of the file. If
>   stop time is not given (i.e, time string is 'x.y,') then analysis goes
>   to end of file.
> ```

For more details see [`man perf-report`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html).

This is present since version 4.10 (Feb 2017). If you run an older kernel you can try to build the userspace tools part of `perf` yourself. In more recent versions it is possible to specify time percent and multiple time ranges.

Comment: Zulan, is there any perf subcommand to convert perf.data to perf.data?

Comment: To filter by `--time`, look at the start timestamp of perf.data using `perf script`. For e.g. mine, shows `redis-server  8117 13887067.396114:          1 cycles:ppp:`. In this case, perf report will filter records only with start time of `13887067.396114`. Any time outside of the range in perf.data will report `The perf.data file has no samples`. I don't understand how this start time is determined by perf or how to make it relative (starting from zero).

Comment: I figured out that the start time is relative to the system uptime (found using `cat /proc/uptime`). I still haven't found a way to make it start from 0.

Answer (score 4):

I still cannot produce a perf_subinterv.data, but I can narrow down the perf trace in textual representation. Then, for further analysis, I can for instance generate a flame graph.

Command to narrow to time interval at 19:29:43 with 3.47s duration:

```
perf script -i ./perf_2016-03-23_192924.468036489.data | awk -v perfdata=./perf_2016-03-23_192924.468036489.data -v interval_start=19:29:43 -v duration=3.47 -f perf_script_cut_interval.awk > perf_2016-03-23_192924.468036489_INTERV_19:29:43.txt
```

Generation of flame graph:

```
stackcollapse-perf.pl perf_2016-03-23_192924.468036489_INTERV_19:29:43.txt | flamegraph.pl > perf_2016-03-23_192924.468036489_INTERV_19:29:43.svg
```

gawk script:

```
#
# Consumes output of 'perf script profile.data' and filters events from a given
# time interval
#
# input variables:
#
# perfdata:
#
#      File with profiling data. Name must be perf_<date>_<time>.data, where
#      <time> has the format <hh><mm><secs>, e.g. perf_2016-03-23_140426.002147215.data
#     
# interval_start:
#
#      Start time of the interval with format <hh><mm><secs>, e.g. 19:29:43.890735
#
# duration:
#
#      length of the interval
#

BEGIN {
  print("processing", perfdata) > "/dev/stderr"
  # parse timestamp of perf rec start
  match(perfdata, /.*perf_.*_(..)(..)(.+)\.data/, ts_perf_rec)
  # parse interval start
  match(interval_start, /(..):(..):(.+)/ , ts_interval)
  hh=1
  mm=2
  ss=3
  printf("ts_perf_rec            = %02d:%02d:%05f\n", ts_perf_rec[hh], ts_perf_rec[mm], ts_perf_rec[ss]) > "/dev/stderr"
  printf("ts_interval            = %02d:%02d:%05f\n", ts_interval[hh], ts_interval[mm], ts_interval[ss]) > "/dev/stderr"
  # current line belongs to header
  in_header = 1
  # current line belongs to selected interval
  in_interval = 0

  # first timestamp in perf.data
  first_ts = -1
  FS="[ :]"
}

# find end of header
/^[^#]/ {
  if (in_header) {
    in_header = 0
  }
}

# find timestamps
# example line: java 15950 515784.682786: cycles: 
/^.+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+:/ {
  cur_ts = $3 + 0.0
  if (first_ts == -1) {
    # translate ts_interval to profile data timestamps by identifying the first
    # timestamp with ts_perf_rec
    first_ts = cur_ts

    # delta_recstart_intervalstart is the time difference from the first
    # profiling event to the filter interval
    delta_recstart_intervalstart[ss] = ts_interval[ss] - ts_perf_rec[ss]
    if (delta_recstart_intervalstart[ss] < 0) {
      delta_recstart_intervalstart[ss] += 60
      delta_recstart_intervalstart[mm] = -1
    }
    delta_recstart_intervalstart[mm] += ts_interval[mm] - ts_perf_rec[mm]
    if (delta_recstart_intervalstart[mm] < 0) {
      delta_recstart_intervalstart[mm] += 60
      delta_recstart_intervalstart[hh] = -1
    }
    delta_recstart_intervalstart[hh] += ts_interval[hh] - ts_perf_rec[hh]

    # beginning and end of the interval in profiling timestamps
    interval_begin_s = delta_recstart_intervalstart[hh] * 3600 + delta_recstart_intervalstart[mm] * 60 + delta_recstart_intervalstart[ss] + first_ts
    interval_end_s = interval_begin_s + duration

    printf("ts_perf_rec                  = %02d:%02d:%05f\n", ts_perf_rec[hh], ts_perf_rec[mm], ts_perf_rec[ss]) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf("first_ts                     = %f\n", first_ts) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf("ts_interval                  = %02d:%02d:%05f\n", ts_interval[hh], ts_interval[mm], ts_interval[ss]) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf("delta_recstart_intervalstart = %02d:%02d:%05f\n",
           delta_recstart_intervalstart[hh], delta_recstart_intervalstart[mm], delta_recstart_intervalstart[ss]) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf("duration                     = %f\n", duration) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf("interval_begin_s             = %05f\n", interval_begin_s) > "/dev/stderr"
    printf("interval_end_s               = %05f\n", interval_end_s) > "/dev/stderr"
  }

  in_interval = ((cur_ts >= interval_begin_s) && (cur_ts < interval_end_s))
}

# print every line that belongs to the header or the selected time interval
in_interval || in_header {
  print $0
}
```