# Robust or accurate way to profile system performance using perf with Python subprocess module

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, perf

**Question**

Is there any robust way to use perf in Python subprocess module?

**Situation**

I have an `app.py` benchmark application and I've been using a command `perf stat -e <some events> -- app.py` The problem is that when I use this command, perf will investigate it at the very beginning but there are bunch of setting stuff in the early period. For instance,

```
$ perf stat -e cycles -- app.py
Starting...
Setting 1...
Setting 2...
Setting 3...
Setting 4...
Setting 5...
---perf subprocess point that I'd like to put---
Another application or process comes up and real data transaction starts...
```

In this situation, there is a huge gap between starting point and the real application running point. The point is that the target of `perf` should be another application (let say, `apache` or `memcached`) not parent python application (`app.py`) which set the appropriate option for child process. So, I'd like to leap this period and analyze the real process or subprocess.

I've tried to use `perf` in subprocess context but the problem happens when I use it since `perf` is blocked in running time and doesn't proceed until I interrupt using `Ctrl-c`

I've also seen another post which has the sort of same problem with me but the author who answered [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654499/python-subprocess-running-in-background-before-returning-output) doesn't seem like to agree this way. (I didn't try it yet but it seems quite tricky so I just want to know is there any way around)

So, please let me know if there is better option for this.

**Update**

Thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854661/robust-or-accurate-way-to-profile-system-performance-using-perf-with-python-subp?noredirect=1#comment90662602_51854661), I've got an idea. I didn't know what *long running* means so I searched and found [this link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/). I think it could be possible logic for my code. I'm still working on it

Comment: if the process you want to profile is long-running, you can manually *attach* a `perf stat` to it after it starts.  Use `perf stat -p 1234`.  All the usual `perf stat` options apply, like `-d` for more cache-miss stuff, `-I 1000` to print `stat` output every 1-second interval, or `-e blah,blah,uops_issued.any` and/or whatever other events you want to profile.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm... if you are saying that I should use `-p` to certain child process, there is another problem. The child processes are many. The whole child processes are same yet another instance so it's not that simple to use _attach_ option. I'm tryting to execute a sort of like `python app.py` and want to put `perf` cmd in the middle of application because I think this would skip the setting process

Comment: Specifially, I think I will use cmd, `perf stat -e cycles -a` in subprocess since `-a` is basically running on system wide. The main reason why I want to do this is to get a better result. The setting period is quite long which takes about 10 seconds, meanwhile perf is running and this figure is total useless. At some point, the real transaction between server and client comes up and CPU starts to work and I want to catch this moment more by cutting any the period of CPU idle time.

Comment: If you want to capture exactly the subprocess you launch, then you should follow the answers of the linked question. [This doesn't look overly complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654592/620382). Update your question to indicate if there are any troubles when applying the existing answers - *"I didn't try it yet"* is a **very bad sign** for a question. If need be check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531753/620382).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Zulan. I will consider your advice. As I already posted on comment before, I'm not targeting a specific subprocess or child process since there are many subprocesses (Let say, 10 `apache` are made by subprocess module. Then, `perf` should be created 10 times. That's nonsense.)  So, I decided to use `-a` option. I will update my question and answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import signal

class Perf():
    __info__ = ["core", "file"]

    def __init__(self, core, file="log")
        self.__rootDir = "/"
        self.__p = None
        self.__core = core
        self.__file = __class_.__name__ + "." + file + ".core-" + core + ".csv"

    def start(self):
        path = os.path.join(self.__rootDir + self.__file)
        cmd = "perf stat -M CPU_Utilization -a -x , -o " + path
        args = shlex.split(cmd)
        self.__p = subprocess.Popen(args) # There are bunch of options

    def stop(self):
        os.kill(self.__p.pid, signal.SIGINT) # Instead of Popen.kill(), I use Ctrl-C
        self.__p = None
```

It's almost the same with other posts or answers. I just remake it as `class` module. I've been working on this a couple of hours and I found some features may seem to be obvious and you may know or not.

- You should put a right path when you run this Perf class. Subprocess can be run  at anywhere and the moment that process runs is the location of output file.
- I found that this doesn't make `perf` improve perfectly. There is still a gap between initialization and starting point of data transaction which means there is an idle time even if `perf` starts to profile subprocess or child-application right away.
- This code needs to be improved to support `PATH` variable. I've been trying to put another path to command which is not system-wide using `os.environ['PATH']` but somehow I am still stuck.